# Start and stop a repeating task in a thread from a button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, schedule

I want to start a task, which should run every 10 seconds, from a GUI made in tkinter. The GUI has a start button and a stop button, with an event to stop the thread.
I am using the schedule module and threading to avoid freezing the GUI.

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread, Event, Lock
import schedule
import time
import os


class GUI():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text='Start', command=partial(run_threaded,experiment), width=20,height=2,bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = tk.Button(text='Stop', command=stop_button, width=20,height=2,bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button2.pack()
    
def job():
    print("Task started") 
    print("Task completed") 
        
def experiment():
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)
    while 1:
        schedule.run_pending()
    
def run_threaded(job_func):
    job_thread = Thread(target=job_func)
    job_thread.start()
    if stop_threads.is_set():
        job_thread.join()
        job_thread = None

def start_button():
    run_threaded(experiment)
    
def stop_button():
    global stop_threads
    stop_threads.set()

def main():
    global stop_threads
    thread1=None
    stop_threads = Event()
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The task starts after 10 seconds and repeats periodically, but the stop button does not work and I would like to have the process start immediately, without the initial delay.

Furthermore, every other time I run it, the task starts but the GUI does not appear.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you use `.after` scripts? How long does it take for your `job` function to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
from functools import partial
from threading import Thread

running_job = False


def job():
    print("Task started") 
    print("Task completed") 

def experiment():
    while running_job:
        job()
        # I changed it to 1 sec to make it easier to test
        sleep(1)


class GUI:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        command = partial(run_threaded, experiment)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="Start", command=command)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = tk.Button(text="Stop", command=stop_button)
        self.button2.pack()


def run_threaded(job_func):
    global running_job
    running_job = True
    job_thread = Thread(target=job_func, daemon=True)
    job_thread.start()

def stop_button():
    global running_job
    running_job = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

It uses a global variable named `running_job`. When `running_job` is `True` the `while` loop inside `experiment` can run. When it turns to `False`, `experiment` stops. The problem with this approach is that if you use `tkinter` widgets/variables inside your `job` function, tkinter may crash.

Another approach would be using `.after` scripts instead but for that to work the `job` function shouldn't take long to execute.

Comment: I tried using `.after`, but the `job` function calls functions from another script and takes about one minute to run so this solution works better. Thanks!

Comment: @HYmch96 No problem, I guessed that this was a simplified version of your code and I also guessed that `job` is a function that takes long to execute :D.